# Why does this say no such file or directory when it clearly is a file in that directory?

Tags: python-3.x, file

```
classes = []
with open(r'D:/classes.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        classes.append(line)
for c in classes:
print(c)
```

How can this not work??

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/classes.txt'
```

Comment: Are you by chance using Windows Subsystem for Linux? If so, I don't believe that can access files on other mounted drives than C:\...

Comment: Shouldn't that be a backslash, or does Windows Python work with a forward slash?

Comment: @UncleCarl: it works with a forward slash. I know it's weird to see for Windows.

Comment: The funny thing about forward slashes being supported is you *don't* need to use raw strings. Only unless you want to anyway.